# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - possible expo-updates issue?

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, macos, expo

I'm trying to build React Native app for iOS via Xcode. The project was initialy worked on Windows PC using Expo managed workflow. Since the application I'm building will be used just by support guys in my company, I don't want to publish it to the AppStore (for guys using iPhones), so I want to make a standalone build without the ExpoGo app. To do that, I have ejected the project to bare workflow. Now, after configuring everything on my MacBook (installing Brew, NPM, Pods, Watcher etc.) I'm getting the following error when I try to build my app:

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ app.manifest\ for\ expo-updates /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myAppName-bfzizgdigfiavjaaxczcpfyuwfnp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/EXUpdates.build/Script-46EB2E00013D80.sh (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')
/Xcode/DerivedData/myAppName-bfzizgdigfiavjaaxczcpfyuwfnp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/EXUpdates.build/Script-46EB2E00013D80.sh

Node found at: /usr/local/bin/node
          Welcome to Metro!
       Fast - Scalable - Integrated

node:events:491
   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
   ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
  at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:204:21)
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
  at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (/Users/myusername/Develop/projectFolder/ProjectSubFolder/react-apps/myAppname/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/watchers/NodeWatcher.js:141:12)
  at FSWatcher.emit (node:events:513:28)
  at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:210:12) {
 errno: -24,
 syscall: 'watch',
 code: 'EMFILE',
 filename: null
}
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Node found at: /usr/local/bin/node
          Welcome to Metro!
       Fast - Scalable - Integrated

node:events:491
   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
   ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
  at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:204:21)
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
  at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (/Users/myusername/Develop/projectFolder/ProjectSubFolder/react-apps/myAppname/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/watchers/NodeWatcher.js:141:12)
  at FSWatcher.emit (node:events:513:28)
  at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:210:12) {
 errno: -24,
 syscall: 'watch',
 code: 'EMFILE',
 filename: null
}

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

**My enviroment is following:**

- MacBook Air M1
- Xcode 14.1
- macOS Monterey v12.5
- NPM 8.19.2
- Node v16.18.1
- Homebrew 3.6.12
- Watchman 2022.11.14.00

**I did try various things found on SO:**

- I have tried to do `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`
- Reinstalling Watchman didn't help
- Downgrading Node to v16 (from v18)
- Removing node_modules and running `npm install` again
- Brew cleanup
- Locking and unlocking keychain
- Clean Xcode project
- Trying to do `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` using arch -x86_64
- Install watchman using an x86_64 instance of homebrew
- Run the metro server in a Rosetta terminal
- Run XCode without Rosetta
- Tried running: `sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 16384 16384 && ulimit -n 16384`

What I have noticed: in the **[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates** section under Pods target I did try to check "Run script only when installing" and the app builds sucesfully and I can see it installed on my iPhone. But when I try to open it, I get the splash screen and the app crashes. The following error is then thrown in Xcode:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The embedded manifest is invalid or could not be read. Make sure you have configured expo-updates correctly in your Xcode Build Phases.
```

I'm fighting with this error message for almost a week and I'm completely out of ideas. The only thing I didn't try is creating a new bare project from scratch and copying the code there. That will be my last resort as I really want to get this one up and running.

Is there something wrong with expo-updates that I'm missing? I did try to re-add them but nothing changed. Is there anything else I could do?

Thank you guys in advance!

P. S. since the app is for internal use in my company, I have replaced some names in paths not to reveal too much about it (for example, real app name to "myAppname").

Comment: Hi, did you managed to solve this?